# Question from isi previous years question paper

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Q. Suppose $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then for any $r_{1}, r_{2}, \cdots, r_{n} \in f[a, b]$, prove that there exists $x \in[a, b]$ such that $f(x)=\frac{r_{1}+r_{2}+\cdots+r_{n}}{n}$.

My approach:-

Let,$m=\min \left\{f\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}$ and $M=\max \left\{f\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}$
Then
$$
m \leq \frac{1}{n}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right)+f\left(x_{2}\right)+\cdots+f\left(x_{n}\right)\right) \leq M
$$
Consequently, there is $x_{0} \in[a, b]$ such that
$$
f\left(x_{0}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right)+f\left(x_{2}\right)+\cdots+f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)
$$

Hence done!

Please cheak this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ f $ is continuous at the compact $ [a,b]$, thus $ f([a,b]) $ is a compact $ [m,M] $ with
$$m=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$$
and
$$M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}.$$

On the other hand, there exist $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in[a,b]^n$ such that

$r_i=f(x_i) $ for  $ i=1,2 \cdots,n$.

so

$$\frac{r_1+r_2+...+r_n}{n}=\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+...+f(x_n)}{n}$$

with
$$m\le f(x_i)\le M$$

thus

$$m\le \frac{r_1+r_2+...+r_n}{n}\le M$$

which means that

$$\frac{r_1+r_2+...+r_n}{n}\in f([a,b])$$

Comment: Thank you @hamam

Comment: You are Welcome.